# Http GET query parameter with "false" value is disappeared

Tags: angular, httpclient

Having a get request

```
this.http.get(`/writers/rating/`, { params: { probation: 'false' } })
```

The URL in the in the end will be not `'/writers/rating?probation=false'`
instead it skips the falsy query parameter `'/writers/rating'`.
Why is that?
Does that have something to do with the Url-encoding?

Comment: You need to pass boolean value as a string.

Answer (score 0):

`URLs` are `strings` and all values in a `URL` are `strings`. So, when you are pass `boolean` value as `query param` then it will ignore it.

So your code should like below:

```
this.http.get(`/writers/rating/`, { params: { probation: 'false' } })
```

Comment: sorry, my typo. It is actually { probation: 'false' }

Answer (score 0):

This error was project-related so the parameters with 'false' value were striped out in the interceptor.